# How do I add data to http request

Tags: python, http

Here is my code:

```
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

urllib2.install_opener(opener)

opener.add_data(json_data)  #runtime error on this line

r = None
try:
    r = opener.open(config.get_url())
except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
   print "..."
```

I get a runtime error:  opener.add_data(get_json)
AttributeError: OpenerDirector instance has no attribute 'add_data'

How can I add request json data to this request?

Comment: Not an answer to this, but in general everything is easier if you use the `requests` module (needs separate install).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it as an argument to the `open` method (it needs to be url-encoded first):

```
import urllib

try:
    r = opener.open(config.get_url(), data=urllib.urlencode(json_data))
except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
   print "..."
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.OpenerDirector.open) of the open method:

> `OpenerDirector.open(url[, data][, timeout])`
>
> Open the given url (which can be a request object or a string), optionally passing the given data.

You can find the documentation by noting that `opener` is a `urllib2.OpenDirector` instance:

```
>>> opener
<urllib2.OpenerDirector instance at 0x1011acef0>
```

Or by doing `help(opener)`, which shows:

```
class OpenerDirector
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __init__(self)
 |  
 |  add_handler(self, handler)
 |  
 |  close(self)
 |  
 |  error(self, proto, *args)
 |  
 |  open(self, fullurl, data=None, timeout=<object object>)
```

Comment: Where is the data= documented?  I couldn't find it.

Comment: @user619818: See link added to post.

Comment: Also my data is json and I get runtime error TypeError: must be string or buffer, not dict

Comment: @user619818: Yep, I had just added that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're doing is sending a requests I **highly** recommend using requests:

```
import requests
    data = {"param": value}
    url = your_url
    cookie = your_cookie
    requests.get(your_url, data=data, cookie=cookie)
```

you can access the ._content attribute of the response to get the raw http response.

See [this](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) for more requests documentation.

This gist should give you a good idea as to why you should use requests instead of urllib: https://gist.github.com/kennethreitz/973705